# Weight brush tool not working

Tags: error

I was just following the blender guru tutorial on [image] level 2 part 1, and towards the end, he switches to the weight paint tool, my problem is that the paint draws toward the sides and the bottom only, but refuses to draw towards the top as seen in the picture

blender file:[image]

Comment: Could you post the .blend please? You can use this to do that: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=GZBBLAGY" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/GZBBLAGY/)

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need to edit the question and paste that code to it. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: yea sorry my bad still new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so, in edit mode you've hidden some of the mesh, which causes the weight paint not to work:

[image]

Just unhide all the mesh in edit mode <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and you can weight paint again :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: thx alot man, that worked!

Comment: If that worked out, please accept the answer @nour7500